# These lines of Ramcharitmanas belong to which descent (Kanda) of the book?

Tags: identification-request, ramcharitmanas

**मंगल भवन अमंगल हारी द्रवहु सुदसरथ अचर बिहारी**

I know this is a very famous chaupai of the holy text but sadly I don't know where it is written.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These lines are found in [Ramacharitamanasa, Bala Kanda](https://www.ramcharitmanas.iitk.ac.in/content/11112).

> चौपाई
>   झूठेउ सत्य जाहि बिनु जानें। जिमि भुजंग बिनु रजु पहिचानें।। 
>   जेहि जानें जग जाइ हेराई। जागें जथा सपन भ्रम जाई।।
>   बंदउँ बालरूप सोई रामू। सब सिधि सुलभ जपत जिसु नामू।। 
>   **मंगल भवन अमंगल हारी। द्रवउ सो दसरथ अजिर बिहारी**।।
>   करि प्रनाम रामहि त्रिपुरारी। हरषि सुधा सम गिरा उचारी।। 
>   धन्य धन्य गिरिराजकुमारी। तुम्ह समान नहिं कोउ उपकारी।।
>   पूँछेहु रघुपति कथा प्रसंगा। सकल लोक जग पावनि गंगा।। 
>   तुम्ह रघुबीर चरन अनुरागी। कीन्हहु प्रस्न जगत हित लागी।।
>
> Due to lack of knowledge about Sri Råma even the unreal passes for real, just
>   as ignorance about a rope leads us to mistake it for a snake. Even so the moment we
>   know Him the world of matter vanishes, just as the delusion of a dream disappears as
>   soon as we wake up. Him do I reverence in the form of a Child, the repetition of whose
>   Name brings all kinds of success within our easy reach. May that Home of bliss and
>   Bane of woe take compassion on meóHe who sports in the courtyard of king
>   Dasaratha.î After thus paying homage to Råma, the Slayer of the demon Tripura joyfully spoke in mellifluous accents as follows: ìYou are indeed blessed and worthy of applause,
>   O daughter of the mountain-king; there is no such benefactor as you. You have asked
>   Me to repeat the history of the Lord of Raghus, which is potent enough to sanctify all the
>   spheres even as the Gangå purifies the whole world. You are full of love for the feet of
>   the Hero of Raghuís race; You have put questions to Me only with an eye to the good
>   of the world.
>
> दोहा/सोरठा
>   रामकृपा तें पारबति सपनेहुँ तव मन माहिं। 
>   सोक मोह संदेह भ्रम मम बिचार कछु नाहिं।।112।।
>
> By the blessing of Råma, O Pårvat∂, not even in dream can grief, infatuation,
>   doubt or error enter your mind, so far as I can judge.