# Meaning of "dravau" and "ajir" in "Mangal Bhavan" chaupai

Tags: rama, ramcharitmanas

I know this is more related to language stack exchange but I am not so sure there are enough people expert on Awadhi there. One of the most famous line of Shriramacharitmanas:

> बंदउँ बालरूप सोई रामू। सब सिधि सुलभ जपत जिसु नामू।।
>
> **मंगल भवन अमंगल हारी। द्रवउ सो दसरथ अजिर बिहारी।।**

As per [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21333/these-lines-of-ramcharitmanas-belong-to-which-descent-kanda-of-the-book) answer, it translate to following:

> Him do I reverence in the form of a Child, the repetition of whose Name brings all kinds of success within our easy reach. May that Home of bliss and Bane of woe take compassion on meóHe who sports in the courtyard of king Dasaratha.

But I would like to know the exact meaning of **द्रवउ** and **अजिर**. My guess is अजिर means आँगन  and dravau means दौरना. Can anyone of you confirm?

Comment: Yes ajir means aangan. Dravau means melt or become kripalu towards bhaktas. That’s why In aranya kand he says : जाते बेगि द्रवउँ मैं भाई सो मम भगति भगत सुखदाई। जिससे मैं शीघ्र द्रवित होता हूँ (पिघलता हूँ/ प्रसन्न होता हूँ) वह मेरी भक्ति है, जो भक्तों को सुख देने वाली है. So the line would mean - जो प्रभु मंगल के भवन (भंडार) हैं और अमंगल को हरने वाले हैं, जो दशरथ महाराज के आँगन में विचरण करते हैं वह प्रभु शीघ्र पिघलें या प्रसन्न हों (हम पर)

Comment: @Archit makes sense, thanks a lot for your reply